# on option select show div

Tags: jquery

ok, so I'm a complete noob when it comes to jQuery, but this is something I want to change over the next year or so if I can find the time!!

I have the following for the dropdown options

```
<select id="shipping_method_id" name="shipping_method_id">
    <option value="6">North Island - New Zealand</option>
    <option value="7">South Island - New Zealand</option>
    <option value="8">Australia</option>
</select>
```

What I want to have is when someone selects Australia from the list I want it to show a div.

When someone selects an option from the list, the page reloads and updates the shipping price.

This is probably really really simple, but I just can't get it working, I've tried this http://jsfiddle.net/JSyLV/910/ but it won't work :(

Comment: I would assume you want it to hide again when the user then selects something else.  Is this correct?

Comment: If someones answer did solve this please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the jQuery .change event.

```
jQuery('#shipping_method_id').change(function(){           
    if(jQuery(this).val() === '8'  ){
        jQuery("#hide_my_ass").slideDown();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JSyLV/920/

**EDIT**

```
jQuery('#shipping_method_id').change(function(){           
    window.location = window.location + '?postPrice=' + jQuery(this).val();
});​
```

Then in PHP you have access to the get variable $_GET['postPrice'] which you can then output as the price.
http://jsfiddle.net/JSyLV/931/

Comment: Your jsfiddle is the one the OP posted ;)

Comment: Hey Charlie, thanks for that, it did work, however I should have mentioned in my original post that when the option is selected, the page reloads to update the shipping price.

Comment: Why don't you just change the price with javascript and then validate it via PHP.

Comment: I'm using a WordPress plugin and modify the code of it will cause me issues when it comes to updates.

Comment: I've added another fiddle, hopefully this helps. The fiddle will not work though as you can't redirect. You'll have to run it locally.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an event listener to call this code:

```
$("#shipping_method_id").change(function(){
   if($(this).val() == '8'){
       $("#hide_my_ass").slideDown();
   }    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JSyLV/913/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#shipping_method_id').change(function(){  //call the change function 
if($(this).val()==8){   //check if selected val is 8 (australia)
   $('#hide_my_ass').show();   //if yes show
}else{
   $('#hide_my_ass').hide();  //else hide
}
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JSyLV/928/